# I got problem when install react js on laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

i'm trying to install react js on laravel, but when I tried input command "php artisan ui react" it's became error like on the image, have any idea for this case ? thank's

[image]

Comment: Did you run ``composer require laravel/ui`` in your project first?

Comment: i already do that

Answer (score 1):

It's done, it happen cause I put js folder on public folder, which should be the js folder must on resource folder

Comment: your answer worked for me. thanks @steven-a

Answer (score 0):

As per laravel requirement for reactjs. You should have to install UI package from composser.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

`composer require laravel/ui` 
after that 
`php artisan ui react` for generating the basic scaffolding.